# how to treat multiline text as only one line in cut command in sh or bash

Tags: bash, sh

I have this file named filename and the content is

```
export k="multiline_v"
```

for example

```
export k="kdk=dkdk
kdkdkdk=kdkd
ldldldsgg"
```

I want to use cut to get k and

my approach was this

```
cat filename | cut -d "=" -f 1
```

but it is treating it multiline and it returns

```
export aa
kdkdkd
kdkdkkd
```

How should I do this? I prefer to be able to use the same command in both sh and bash.

My goal is to get `export k` just from the first line - I just care about what exist in the first line

Comment: `cut` processes its input line by line.

Comment: It simply outputs the specified fields from each line of the input. How is it supposed to know where multiline input ends?

Comment: On what operating system? Which `cut`?

Comment: @Barmar GNU coreutils cut has a `-z` option to use `\0` as the line delimiter.

Comment: linux operating system

Comment: You are getting further and further down the rabbit hole of fragile, inefficient,non-portable code.

Comment: If we can assume from your previous question(s) that the first line is the only one you care about, just use `IFS='=' read k _ < filename`. `read` only reads one line from the given file, then splits that line into `export k` and `"kdk=dkdk` based on the number of arguments `read` received. You can ignore `_`; it's just the conventional name for a variable whose value you don't care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us what OS you are using, but the GNU coreutils version of `cut`, which should be the default `cut` on most Linux systems, has a `-` option:

```
       -z, --zero-terminated
              line delimiter is NUL, not newline
```

So you can do:

```
terdon@oregano foo $ cut -z -d= -f 1 filename 
export kterdon@oregano foo $
```

Note how my prompt appears right next to the output. That's because, since we're using `-z` to slurp the whole file, there is no trailing newline. So you could do:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(cut -z -d= -f 1 filename)"
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
export k
```

Now bash complains about the `\0`, which is added by `cut -z`. You can remove that too:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(cut -z -d= -f 1 filename | tr -d '\0')"
export k
```

Of course, if you know it's always on the first line, you could simply do:

```
$ head -n1 filename | cut -d= -f1
export k
```

Or, you could just use different tools:

1. GNU `grep`

   ```
   $ grep -m1 -oP '^[^=]+' filename 
   export k
   ```
2. Awk

   ```
   $ awk -F= '{print $1; exit}' filename 
   export k
   ```
3. sed (note that this one only works if the `=` you want is on the first line)

   ```
   $ sed -nE 's/([^=]*)=.*/\1/p;q' filename 
   export k
   ```
4. Perl

   ```
   $ perl -lne 'do{print $1; exit} if /([^=]*)=/' filename
   export k
   ```

Comment: Regarding "if you know it's always on the first line, you could simply do `head -n1 filename | cut -d= -f1`" - it needs to be on the first line for `cut -z -d= -f 1 filename` to work too, otherwise the output will include all the preceding lines.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, but I would expect that to be the desired result in that case: that's the first `=` so everything before it should be returned. The `sed` approach, however, will `q`uit after the first line irrespective of whether a match was found.

Comment: I highly doubt if given input such as from `printf 'foo\nbar\nexport k="multiline_v"\n'` the OP would want output of `foo<LF>bar<LF>export k`, as would be output by `cut -z -d= -f 1`, rather than just `export k`.